# What fields/properties can be queried from Facebook Graph API on a Place object?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm doing a query of this form:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Beshoff&fields=likes,checkins,products,name,talking_about_count,description,category&type=place&center=37.327453,-121.813102&distance=400
```

I am interested in finding out the exhaustive list of fields that can be selected for a Place object.

In particular, on the facebook page for a specific place, there are often multiple categories listed which I have been unable to figure out if it's possible to retrieve using the Graph API.

e.g. On https://www.facebook.com/BeshoffInfiniti, there is an entry "Car Dealership" but the graph api call above returns "Local business".

Answer (score 1):

If you leave out the "fields" attribute in your query you will get all the fields. The number of fields depends on the object type (for example owned pages vs. wiki pages)

Answer (score 0):

Don't just look at the Graph API. Take a look at [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/). There are different fields available in FQL vs. the API. And yes, using the `distance` function you can look for places in an area.

[Graph API](http://graph.facebook.com/beshoffinfiniti?fields=category) != [FQL](http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+categories+FROM+page+WHERE+username+=+%22BeshoffInfiniti%22)

Comment: Sadly, FQL will be deprecated soon. For privacy concern I think

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is the Facebook Open Graph schema entry for [Page](http://graph.facebook.com/schema/page) and [Place](http://graph.facebook.com/schema/place).

You'll find all the additional fields for Pages. You can think of places as a subclass of pages.

If you're curious about the types of page that might be returned, try having a look through the [create a page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php) flow.